# 01476. 00000 - "divisor is equal to zero" Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, case, divide-by-zero, nullif

I have the following code as part of a Script:

```
ROUND
(
  (
    (COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ONLINE_SALES > 0 THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END)) 
    / 
    (COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ONLINE_SALES > 0 OR OFFLINE_SALES > 0 THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END))
  ),3
) AS UNIQ_ONLINE_SHOP_RATE
```

when I run the script I get the 'Divizer is equal to zero' erro.

I ran the denominator and numerator separately which both equal zero so I understand the error.

I have tried NULLiF(,0) as so:

```
ROUND
(
  (
    (
      COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ONLINE_SALES > 0 THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) / 
      nullif((COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ONLINE_SALES > 0 OR OFFLINE_SALES > 0 THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END)),0)
    ),3
  ) AS UNIQ_ONLINE_SHOP_RATE
```

but then get 'FROM keyword not found where expected error.

Comment: You might be missing **ROUND((** from the second expression.

Comment: Just forgot to paste it but issue still the same, thank you for looking though :)

Comment: I'm counting 7 open parentheses and only 6 closing ones.
Try this instead   
```ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ONLINE_SALES > 0 THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END)/
            nullif(COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ONLINE_SALES > 0 OR OFFLINE_SALES > 0 THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END),0),3) AS UNIQ_ONLINE_SHOP_RATE```

Comment: So, your divisor is zero, what does that mean?  It means there are no cases where online_sales or offline_sales are positive.  Since your numerator is the same thing for *only* online_sales, then your numerator is also 0 for that case.  A very easy way to handle that then is to say NULLIF(...., 1) [not 0] and then you should get zero when the division occurs.

Comment: As @Nicko said, this is just a typo as you have too many opening braces in your final query which is why you get the syntax error. Remove one of the opening braces and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 options (`CASE`, `NULLIF` and `DECODE`), visually simple to understand - use a CTE to calculate both values, while the main query divides them, taking care about 0 as the denominator:

```
with temp as
  (select
     COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ONLINE_SALES > 0                      THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) val1,
     COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ONLINE_SALES > 0 OR OFFLINE_SALES > 0 THEN CONTACT_KEY ELSE NULL END) val2
   from your_table
  )
select 
  -- using CASE
  val1 / case when val2 = 0 then null else val2 end  as result_1,
  -- using NULLIF
  val1 / nullif(val2, 0)                             as result_2
  -- using DECODE
  val1 / decode(val2, 0, null, val2)                 as result_3  
from temp;
```

Shouldn't be difficult to `round` the result at the end.

Comment: "*This is Oracle, and there's no `NULLIF`*" - I see it different: [NULLIF](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions128.htm#SQLRF00681), I think it exists since Oracle 9i

Comment: OMG, @Wernfried! I've been around for ages and didn't even know NULLIF exists in Oracle. What a shame! I should've - at least - checked it myself first. So sorry and - thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your real query? I assume `ONLINE_SALES > 0` or `OFFLINE_SALES > 0` is the default and `ONLINE_SALES = 0` or `OFFLINE_SALES = 0` is the exception.

Then in most cases your query would result in

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CONTACT_KEY) / COUNT(DISTINCT CONTACT_KEY)
```

which is not so "exciting", i.e. always **1**

With some best-guess I would do:

```
NULLIF(
   ROUND( 
      COUNT(DISTINCT CONTACT_KEY) 
      / 
      NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT ONLINE_SALES), 0) 
   , 3)
, 0) AS UNIQ_ONLINE_SHOP_RATE
```